# Android About page

Tags: android

How to open Settings>About page programmaticlly in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open it by simply using an `Intent`

```
Intent aboutPhone = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS); 
startActivity(aboutPhone);
```

As in Android there are many `Settings` classes and here it would be :

```
android.provider.Settings
```

Comment: Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS not found.

Comment: @Android_IT: Did you tried importing all the classes properly, insure that you must have `import android.provider.Settings;` as I had earlier mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Its available for API Level 8 and above. I need to get this below API Level 8. Is there any other intent to get this?

Comment: @Android_IT: I am not aware of this but you can also try fetching programmatically the diffierent information accordingly available in the API docs and then show it on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is as close as you can get

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS); 
startActivity(i);
```

Takes you to the main settings page. There doesn't seem to be an option to go to the About Phone page.

Comment: There are many `Settings` classes and here it should be `android.provider.Settings`

Answer (score -2):

Short answer you can't .

Long answer all you can do is create an activity and show all the info from about page in your activity by problematically polling out the info from the system

Comment: **-1** @Saurabh : **`Short answer you can't .`** this statement is simply incorrect.